# How to access properties of arraylist associated with a model bean object using spring tags?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

i am stuck with my code and i need help. I want to have access to the properties of the arraylist in the jsp page. Below given are the code snippets and the error. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class Policydocumentsetform implements Serializable{
    ...
          private ArrayList<Document> documentList;
    ...
}



 public class Document implements Serializable{
    ...
    private String txtDisableCheckBox;
    private String ynChkBox;
    ...
}



<c:forEach var="documentlist" items="${policydocumentsetform.documentList}">      
 <c:if test="${documentlist.txtDisableCheckBox=='N'}">
   <form:checkbox path="documentlist.ynChkBox" cssClass="genradio" value="-1"    onclick="selectCheckBox(event.keyCode,this)"/>
```

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'documentlist' of bean class [gc.dms.bean.PolicyDocumentSetForm]
```

Comment: how do you pass Policydocumentsetform to jsp in your controller? beside that - did you make getter method for documentList?

Comment: using this commandName="policydocumentsetform"

Comment: Does `Policydocumentsetform` define a `getDocumentList()`?  If not, it needs too.

Comment: The error doesn't match the EL you've shown.

Comment: I know the EL doesn't contain the error,look above for my question.. my concern is regarding the spring 'path' attribute of the spring tag 'form:checkbox'

Answer (score 5):

The Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'documentlist' of bean class [gc.dms.bean.PolicyDocumentSetForm]
```

might be in

```
<form:checkbox path="documentlist.ynChkBox" //Here, is the problem
               cssClass="genradio"
               value="-1"
               onclick="selectCheckBox(event.keyCode,this)"/>
```

Solution,

am considering you have added `Policydocumentsetform` insatance as `commandName` or `modelAttribute` and trying to use spring checkbox(`<form:checkbox..`) ,if so do like:

```
<form:form commandName="policydocumentsetform"...>

<c:forEach var="document" items="${policydocumentsetform.documentList}" varStatus="documentLoop">      
 <c:if test="${document.txtDisableCheckBox=='N'}">
   <form:checkbox path="documentList[${documentLoop.index}].ynChkBox"
                  cssClass="genradio"
                  value="-1"               
                  onclick="selectCheckBox(event.keyCode,this)"/>
 </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

<sub>Note:
make sure getters and setters are available in `Policydocumentsetform` and `Document`</sub>

Comment: Yeah it worked perfectly,but i have one query..Instead of writing this path="documentList[${documentLoop.index}].ynChkBox" , could it not be written like this  path="document[${documentLoop.index}].ynChkBox"?? i am saying so because document is the already declared alias for 'policydocumentsetform.documentList' .

Comment: if worked perfectly, accept it with +1, and `documentList[${documentLoop.index}].ynChkBox` is the proper you cannot write `document[${documentLoop.index}].ynChkBox` it means document property is not available in `Policydocumentsetform` but in `private ArrayList<Document> documentList`.